# Graph Coloring All Solutions

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, computation-theory, graph-coloring

I have a problem that is reducible to graph coloring. However, I am interested in obtaining all valid colorings (not just one) for a given number of colors.

Is there a standard known approach that will not only solve the problem, but also find all valid colorings?

Comment: Are you saying that there is no limit on how many colors you can use ?

Comment: Not exactly, what I mean is that for a given number of colors, there may be several different ways to color the graph in a valid way.

Comment: Any of the complete search algorithms should give you all colorings (at least up to some symmetries).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat are you referring to the standard dynamic programming search algorithm for graph coloring? Can you please point me towards one of those algorithms.